# What do the curvature and torsion measure?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Consider a smooth surface for simplicity. What does its curvature measure? What does its Gaussian/Riemannian curvature measure? What does its torsion measure?

What does the Ricci curvature measure?

Comment: I think you can get all them in any textbook on differential geometry. You shall specify your problem.

Comment: None of the textbooks I read deal with examples or interpretation of the concepts, sir. And I shall not specify any further, as this question stems from the most general discussion. @ShuchangZhang

Comment: The word "curvature" is vague: there are at least 10 different notions of curvature.  The Gaussian curvature and Riemann curvature tensor are different things.  The word "torsion" also has two different meanings -- namely (1) the "torsion tensor" that measures the rotation of vectors along geodesics, and (2) the torsion of an embedded curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which measures its deviation from being planar.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465603/are-there-simple-examples-of-riemannian-manifolds-with-zero-curvature-and-nonzer/465672#465672) for geometric interpretations of the curvature and torsion.

Comment: If the best answer is just a link to a previous question, that means the question itself is a duplicate of that one, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search the questions on MSE and/or MO, I think you will,find some pretty good insights into these topics; if I recall correctly, these topics have come up more than once; many times, in fact.  For example, this one might be a good place to start:

[Geometric interpretation of connection forms, torsion forms, curvature forms, etc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47095/geometric-interpretation-of-connection-forms-torsion-forms-curvature-forms-et)

Good luck in you searches!

Answer (score 1):

The curvature literally measure how sharp a curve is at a certain point. For example if you have a circle of small radius then the curvature (which is given by $\frac{1}{R}$ for a circle) at any given point will have a large curvature which means that it is bending sharply. Similarly, if you have a large radius then the curvature will be much smaller which means that it is bending less sharply. The Torsion of a curve measure how sharply it is twisting out of its plane curvature. I perfect example to look at would be the helix. (To be specific when I talk about a small radius I am referring to $R<1$.)

The Ricci curvature tensor provides a way to which the geometry provided by the Riemannian metric might differ from ordinary Euclidean n-space. An application of the Ricci curvature tensor is in General Relativity in connection with the Einstein Field Equations.

Comment: Thank you sir. What do you mean by "plane curvature"?