# What is the geometric interpretation of the Connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvature, general-relativity

I am currently enrolled in a General Relativity course, and was taught about the connection but I can't really wrap my head around it qualitatively. All I can think of is that it must have something to do with the coordinate system that one uses to describe a space(or space-time) but I can't give it a geometric interpretation**(Check the 2nd EDIT)**.
Thank you.

EDIT 1: I am searching for an explanation in terms of the curvature of the space and the coordinates.

EDIT 2: Upon searching for an answer, I found that the relation of the connection with the covariant derivative offers some insight: The connection term in the covariant derivative is an extra term to the normal derivative that is there in order to account for the changes in the coordinate basis vectors. If anybody could use this type of logic to give a complete geometric interpretation of the connection, it would be great!

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with concepts like vector bundles so I'm not sure if the mathematical definition will help you. The geometric intuition should be that a connection allows you to transport vectors along smooth curves. In particular this allows you to differentiate vector fields on a manifold, or in general sections of vector bundles.

Comment: @Qidi unfortunately I am not familiar with vector bundles. So, why does the connection allows us to transport vectors along smooth curves? What does it do, geometrically?

Comment: I'm not sure how you exactly define a connection in your course, so I'm not sure how to explicitly explain it. Usually by a connection(or covariant derivative) one means something that takes 2 vector fields and produce a vector field, this can be interpreted as differentiating a vector field along another. For instance in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the derivative defines a connection. Assume you have a vector field along some curve, then requiring such a field to be parallel exactly means the derivative along the curve is zero. You can try to do the same for e.g. curved surfaces.

Comment: @Qidi Well, we initially defined the connection via the geodesic equation. Afterwards, we defined the covariant derivative and connected the two. But, still I don't understand how to interpret it graphically using this knowledge. For instance, through the definition of the covariant derivative, the connection gives an extra term besides the normal derivative but I do not understand why it is needed except that it makes the covariant derivative a tensor(transforms properly under general transformations).

Comment: I think I have a vague idea of what you are saying. I would say the extra term is there exactly to make it a tensor. Our objective is to generalize differentiation to a curved space, and in this context it is important that our construction does not depend on coordinates. The picture is just as I mentioned, you want to define what parallel fields mean(e.g. on earth the direction north) and you do so by requiring the "correct" derivative to vanish.

Comment: Curvature does not come into play yet for an arbitrary connection. If you further require your connection to be metric and torsion free, then there is a unique connection, the Levi-Civita connection(this is also know as the fundamental theorem of Riemannian geometry)

Comment: @Qidi you said: "Our objective is to generalize differentiation to a curved space, and in this context it is important that our construction does not depend on coordinates". I agree and this is what I am being taught, but there must be a geometrical reason that the "normal" derivative is not good(not a tensor) while the new, covariant derivative is good(a tensor). I can prove it but I can't see it. So, the connection must have to do with the reason that the normal derivative is not good. I just don't have the intuition to interpret the algebra.

Comment: Think of a $2$-dimensional surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is completely clear how you differentiate vector fields. But if you were an ant on the surface that can only detect $2$ dimensions, you don't really notice that from point to point, the tangent plane actually varies in $\mathbb{R}^3$. This change is important since a vector field really takes values in different vector spaces at each point. In the case for the Levi-Civita connection, the additional part(the Christoffel symbols) captures this change from point to point as determined by the metric.

Comment: @Qidi So, the normal derivative is the derivative in one tangent vector space and it works by itself when we can move at every point of the embedding space(like in our multivariable calculus course) but this does not work in general when we are confined on an object(like a sphere) that is embedded in that space? Thus, by also including the connection term we also include the change from going to one tangent plane to another while moving on that object? If so, please clarify something for me: what does the ant not notice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48761/discussion-between-qidi-and-thequantumman).

Comment: @Qidi of course

Comment: You may find the following discussion to be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/47095/272316c

Comment: @Qidi I can not find the chat room for some reason.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe it helps to look at some simple example.

In this example, I just take the normal Euclidean plane with normal Cartesian coordinates. *However* I attach a non-standard basis to each point. Namely, to describe vectors at point $(x,y)$ I use the basis
$$e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \cos x \\\sin x \end{pmatrix},
e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -\sin x \\\cos x \end{pmatrix}$$
So you see, the basis in general is *different* at different points (and not the slightest related to the metric!). It is, however, differentiable.

Now let's further assume that on my Euclidean plane, I have a constant vector field
$$v(x) = \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$$
So nothing very interesting. Except that I'm now going to express it in my local basis. Then I get
$$v(x) = v^1 e_1 + v^2 e_2 = (a\cos x + b\sin x) e_1 + (-a\sin x + b \cos x) e_2$$
That is, although the vector field is constant, the *components* of the vector field in my contrieved basis are not; instead they depend on $x$ (the reason why they don't also depend on $y$ is only because I chose the basis that way).

In particular, we get for the partial derivatives of the components:
\begin{align}
v^1{}_{,x} &= -a\sin x + b\cos x & v^1{}_{,y} &= 0\\
v^2{}_{,x} &= -a\cos x - b\sin x & v^2{}_{,y} &= 0
\end{align}
This apparent variability of the vector field is only due to the change of the basis; we have actually *defined* the vector field to be constant. But of course, not all vector fields are constant, so the question arises: How can we distinguish between actually changing vector fields and component changes that are just artefacts of the vectors?

Well, we are still in an Euclidean space, so we can just calculate the true change. So let's say we start at point $(x,y)$ and move along the path $(x+t,y)$, so we recover the derivative in $x$ direction. Then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}
&= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(v^1 e_1 + v^2 e_2)\\
&= v^1{}_{,x} e_1 + v^1 e_{1,x} + v^2{}_{,x} e_2 + v^2 e_{2,x}
\end{align}
If we write this "true derivative" with semicolon instead of comma, we + therefore get for the components of $\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}$:
$$v^i{}_{;x} = v^i{}_{,x} + v^1 \omega^i(e_{1,x}) + v^2 \omega^i(e_{2,x}) = v^i{}_{,x} + \omega^i(e_{j,x})v^j$$
where I used the notation $\omega^i$ for the dual basis of $e_i$, that is $\omega^i(e_j)=\delta^i_j$, and in the last step the Einstein summation convention.

As you see, the "true" derivative decomposes into two parts: The component derivative, and a correction term. The correction is the contraction of the vector with an object with three indices: An upper and a lower index for the basis, and an additional lower index for the coordinate direction in which we are differentiating. These three-index objects are the connection coefficients, $\Gamma^i_{jk}=\omega^i(e_{j,k})$.

Now of course nobody would choose such a strange basis. Instead, the basis is chosen to point in the direction of the coordinates. This means that the basis indices coincide with the  coordinate indices; that is, all indices correspond to the same set of directions. Therefore you don't have to distinguish between those two types of indices (unlike above, where the basis indices were $1$ and $2$, while the coordinate indices were $x$ and $y$).

Answer (score 4):

The key to understanding this cycle of ideas is parallel transport. In classical physics we are use to moving vectors around. Take a vector starting at one point and transport the vector parallel to itself so that it now starts at another point. This also comes into play when we differentiate a vector field. For that we must compare two vectors with different (but close by) initial points. Here again we move one of the vectors parallel to itself so that the two vectors have the same initial point and then we take the difference etc.

However if we traverse a path along a curved surface how do we move a vector parallel with itself ? What is the CONNECTION between vectors at different points ? It turns out that there is a well defined notion of parallel transport along any curve on a surface, although it is somewhat counterintuitive. Take the case of traversing a line of latitude different from the equator. Start with a vector pointing toward the north pole, as you move taking the vector parallel to itself it will no longer point to the pole. And if you make a circuit of the line of latitude and return to your starting point the vector will no longer coincide with the vector you started with. 
And the closer that line of latitude is to the pole the greater the discrepancy.

Covariant differentiation is the differentiation of a vector field along a path where in order to compare nearby vectors we move them parallel according to the parallel transport on the surface. If for example we start with one vector and create a vector field along a curve by transporting that vector parallel, the the covariant derivative of this field will be zero. In fact that is one way to define the concept of parallel transport. Covariant differentiation and parallel transport are expression of the same thing. May books take covariant differentiation as the basic concept.

Finally, how does a connection arise ? It is defined by the Christoffel symbols, as you know, and these come from differentiating the vectors on the surface in three dimensional space, thus no longer getting a vector tangent to the surface, and then projecting onto the tangent plane of the surface. This is seen in the defining equations

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{r}_{uu}&=\Gamma_{11}^1  \ \mathbf{r}_{u} + \Gamma_{11}^2  \ \mathbf{r}_{v} +L  \ \mathbf{N}\\
\mathbf{r}_{uv}&=\Gamma_{12}^1  \ \mathbf{r}_{u} + \Gamma_{12}^2  \ \mathbf{r}_{v} +M  \ \mathbf{N}\\
\mathbf{r}_{vv}&=\Gamma_{22}^1  \ \mathbf{r}_{u} + \Gamma_{22}^2  \ \mathbf{r}_{v} +N  \ \mathbf{N}\\
\end{align*}

Where $\mathbf{N}$ is the normal to the surface.

A few final comments, a connection is weaker than a Riemann metric. A metric allows one to define both a connection and a curvature. But the connection alone does not define the curvature. It is a mistake to think it has to do with  the coordinate system, it is a geometric idea. And I have been speaking of surfaces as if they were imbedded in three dimensional space, this is a  source of intuition but the ideas generalise to higher dimensional manifolds, not imbedded  in space.

Well, there is more to be said but I hope this helps and gives you an intuition with which to move forward.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I have two question though if you are willing to answer them: What information does the connection lack that the metric has that makes it weaker than the metric? Also, "It is a mistake to think it has to do with the coordinate system, it is a geometric idea": I did  not understand it; doesn't the connection has to do with the coordinate system?

Comment: Both good questions. Not sure I have good answers. But I can say that curvature is defined by $K=\frac{R_{1212}}{|g|}$, and $R_{1212}$ involves only the christoffel symbols, and $|g|$ is an area measure,  so I would suggest that this is the missing ingredient. As for the second remark, I just meant that the ideas of differential geometry are independent of the coordinate systems used, on the other hand the christoffel symbols are not a tensor, so maybe that remark should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: Oh ok, good. Thanks again. You said that you have a lot more to say on this topic, so would it be too much to ask to edit your answer to include some more of your great insights! I am missing intuition at the moment and it would really help!

Comment: At the moment I cannot think of anything I can reasonably add to my answer. I hope that reading the first paragraphs will give you some intuition, check out Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by DoCarmo.

Answer (score 0):

A NEW SUGGESTION

If we combine GR and QT by adding their "co-variant" derivatives then we get a double curvature tensor.

f;n = f,n + [Hn , f]– +[Gn , f]+ = f,n + Hn f – f Hn + Gn f+ f Gn
(to be called the QTGR-derivative of f in 4-D spacetime)

for short f;n = f,n+ Xn f + f Yn and similarly f;p = f,p+ Xp f + f Yp (where X (=G+H) and Y (=G–H) )

This gives, after some algebraic effort using the classical curvature tensor derivation :

f;np –  f;pn =  Rnp f + f Řnp

Rnp = Gn,p – Gp,n +[Gp,Gn]– + Hn,p – Hp,n +[Hp,Hn]– +[Hp,Gn]– +[Gp,Hn]–

Řnp = Gn,p – Gp,n +[Gn,Gp]– + Hp,n – Hn,p +[Hn,Hp]– +[Hp,Gn]– +[Gp,Hn]–

(The n and p above are subscripts, +/- signs after brackets are for anti-commutators and commutators)

G represents the part played by Christoffel connection Gamma through an anti-commutator, and H represents the part played by the 4-D Hamiltonian through a commutator.

f is any 4*4 matrix representing a space-time dynamics of the system.

We have thus two curvature tensor-operators - classical GR has missed out the second Řnp. Hence classical GR is an incomplete theory.

Mass should get a complex phase as m0.A.exp(i.theta)

The energy momentum tensor is then : Tjk= m0.A.exp(i.theta) ujuk/v0

(j, k and 0 are subscripts, u is 4-velocity and the ratio m0/v0 the rest-mass/rest-volume of a "particle", A is "wave"-amplitude, with j, k, n and p = 0,1,2,3 )

The phase theta includes all non-gravity forces, fields and gauges.

A theory formulated thus will combine GR and QT in 4-D.